"Text Recognition Issues in License Plate Recognition Using YOLO and EasyOCR"
Problem
I am working on a license plate recognition system using YOLOv8 for detection and EasyOCR for text recognition. While YOLO correctly detects license plate regions, the OCR results are often inaccurate for Arabic text and numbers.
Examples of detected text:
Detected: "اباز", which is irrelevant.
Detected: "الراق", which is a partial match to "العراق".
Numbers like "٢٦٠٤٩٩" are detected accurately.
What I’ve Tried
Pipeline Setup:
YOLOv8 detects the license plate and extracts its bounding box.
EasyOCR processes the cropped license plate for text recognition.
Text Correction:
Used difflib.get_close_matches() to match OCR-detected text with predefined words (e.g., "العراق", "دهوك").
Applied confidence thresholds to filter low-confidence results.
Image Preprocessing:
Converted the plate region to grayscale.
Resized the region to enhance OCR performance.
Minimal Reproducible Example
import cv2
import easyocr
from ultralytics import YOLO

def detect_plate_with_yolo(image_path, model_path="yolov8n.pt"):
    model = YOLO(model_path)
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    results = model(img)
    detections = results[0].boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy()
    if detections:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, detections[0])
        return img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    return None

def perform_ocr_on_plate(plate_img):
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['ar', 'en'], gpu=False)
    plate_gray = cv2.cvtColor(plate_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return reader.readtext(plate_gray, detail=1)

plate_img = detect_plate_with_yolo("path/to/image.jpg")
if plate_img is not None:
    detected_text = perform_ocr_on_plate(plate_img)
    print(detected_text)

Expected vs. Actual Behavior
Expected: Correct recognition of Arabic text and numbers (e.g., "العراق").
Actual: Partial matches (e.g., "الراق") or irrelevant results (e.g., "اباز").
Questions
How can I improve OCR accuracy for Arabic license plates with EasyOCR?
Are there better alternatives to difflib.get_close_matches() for text correction?
What additional preprocessing steps might help improve OCR performance?

I've never understood why people attempt to OCR when they're already using YOLO for detection.  Just use YOLO to detect!  Like this:  https://github.com/stephanecharette/DarkPlate  You'd then get results like this:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/ml/iranian_plates.html  See this tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jz97_-PCxl4
